# How can I get current Value of Selected button from the following?

Tags: javascript, html, css

We have three buttons(English, Hindi & Urdu). How I can get the value of Selected button in JavaScript function?

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" checked> English
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"> Hindi
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3"> Urdu
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean “should not be able to select English again”? A radio button is checked or unchecked. Clicking on a checked button doesn’t do anything. Also the title off your question is totally different than your question. Please clarify what you’re trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly set value to your radio buttons then get buttons and bind event listener.
and you can get value of button from event target as following:

```js
let btns= document.getElementsByName("options");

for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click",function(e) {         
       console.log(e.target.value);
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" checked value="English">English
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"value="Hindi">Hindi
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" value="Urdu">Urdu
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This:
https://jsfiddle.net/f7ed1o0n/

```
 $('input[name="options"]').change(function(){
   alert($(this).val());
   $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('input[type="radio"]').attr('disabled', 
   'disabled');
 });
```